# Dynamically appending data to the URL Query String while navigating between pages

Tags: php, mysql, url

This is just a project for my own learning purposes. For my project, users will be able to create polls and answer them. Each survey will have its own unique ID and can be accessed by its unique URL.

My problem is this. I know I can get around doing it this way, but this is a learning experience. When the user submits this form:

```
    <form name="createPoll" action="polls.php" method="post">
        Poll Title: <input name="pollTitle" type="text" /><br />
        Option 1: <input name="pollOption" type="text" /><br />
        Option 2: <input name="pollOption" type="text" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value ="Submit Poll" /><br />
    </form>
```

I want to run a script that will add this to my MySQL database and use the pollID that this script will generate for the URL like this:

```
    http://www.mydomainname.com/polls.php?pollID=12345
```

where "12345" is the unique ID of the poll. My question is this:

What is the best way to bring the user to http://www.mydomainname.com/polls.php?pollID=12345 (assuming that the generated pollID will be '12345') on the submission of my form? Do I have to set the header in php in order to redirect them once the script has created the unique pollID?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way would be to generate the ID before the submission. (ie. Generate the ID and append it to your form action) Then use that id to create the poll in the database. Otherwise, you'd have to redirect with headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way: There is two inputs named "pollOption", be carefull :)

Your INSERT codes may be like that

```
$id=rand(100000,9999999999999999);
$checkid=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM ID WHERE ID='$id'");
$checkidx=mysql_fetch_array($checkid);

if($_POST and $checkidx==null){
$title=$_POST['pollTitle'];
$opt1=$_POST['pollOption1'];
$opt2=$_POST['pollOption2'];
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ID,title,option1,option2 VALUES ('$id','$title','$opt1','$opt2')");
echo "Added! You re redirecting";
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://www.mydomainname.com/polls.php?pollID=<?echo $id; ?>">

<?
}
```

And your polls.php may be like that;

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
if($id!=null){
$idget=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE ID='$id'");
$idgetx=mysql_fetch_array($idget);

echo $idgetx[0] . $idgetx[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was sloppy with that. forgot to rename the field after I copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the url, then use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect the page.

e.g.:

```
$id = 12345;

$url = 'http://www.mydomainname.com/polls.php?pollID=' . $id;
header('Location: ' . $url);
```